# Protocol implementation class type check

Tags: python, type-hinting, mypy, typechecking, python-typing

I haven't been able to figure out if this is at all possible.

Given the following code, I'd like `mypy` to report error for both cases:

```py
from dataclasses import dataclass
from typing import Generic, Protocol, Type, TypeVar

T = TypeVar("T")

class MyProto(Protocol):
    attr: str

class Impl:
    attr: int  # wrong type on purpose for this example

# This util class is an attempt to illustrate what I'm trying to achieve, an answer may very well
# indicate changes to it, if required, to make it work as desired.
@dataclass
class Util(Generic[T]):
   proto: T
   impl: Type[T]

# Case 1
# The following is type checked, and correctly reports the error when the implementation does not
# satisfy the protocol.
C: Type[MyProto] = Impl 

# Case 2
# Where as this is accepted regardless, but I'd like it to report error in case Impl does not
# satisfy MyProto.
util = Util(MyProto, Impl)
```

Example output:

```sh
$ python -m mypy t.py
t.py:22:20: error: Incompatible types in assignment (expression has type "Type[Impl]", variable has type "Type[MyProto]")  [assignment]
    C: Type[MyProto] = Impl 
                       ^
Found 1 error in 1 file (checked 1 source file)
```

The use case is, to be able to register dynamically implementations and their protocols they support, while still being statically type checked. Hope that makes sense.

**Update**

Ok, so I've found that what I have above ought to work, as-is, if only Protocol had a type representation that would actually work. Now, `T` is inferred as `object` rather than `MyProto`, as that is the least common denominator of the two types passed to `Util()` as it were. However, if I explicitly declare that `T` should be `MyProto`, I get closer:

```py
util = Util[MyProto](MyProto, Impl)
```

Gives me what I want, almost:

```sh
[...]
t.py:42:22: error: Argument 1 to "Util" has incompatible type "Type[MyProto]"; expected "MyProto"  [arg-type]
    util = Util[MyProto](MyProto, Impl)
                         ^
t.py:42:31: error: Argument 2 to "Util" has incompatible type "Type[Impl]"; expected "Type[MyProto]"  [arg-type]
    util = Util[MyProto](MyProto, Impl)
                                  ^
```

The error about argument 1 is wrong, the expected type is right, the reported type of the argument is wrong, it should be just `MyProto` or however Protocol classes should be represented by the type system.

The error about argument 2 is correct, and goes away if I fix the `Impl` so it matches the protocol.

So, when it comes to protocols, the lack of proper type representation and the logic for determining the LCD between two types seems to be broken.

Comment: Bug reported: https://github.com/python/mypy/issues/10988

Comment: And closed. Going with ABCs instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Funny thing that I would find the answer, first after posting the question here (spent a full day struggling with this, until I finally got nudged in the right direction).

```py
# tweaked Util class, thus:
@dataclass
class Util(Generic[T]):
   proto: Type
   impl: Type[T]

# then using it as such, with an explicit generic type:
util = Util[MyProto](MyProto, Impl)
```

```sh
t.py:27:31: error: Argument 2 to "Util" has incompatible type "Type[Impl]"; expected "Type[MyProto]"  [arg-type]
    util = Util[MyProto](MyProto, Impl)
                                  ^
Found 2 errors in 1 file (checked 1 source file)
```

Not the most elegant however, so if any one figures out how to avoid duplicating `MyProto` when constructing the `Util` instance, would be much appreciated.

Also noticed I get a much better error message from `mypy` if I pass in an instance of `Impl`, rather than just the class.

```sh
t.py:27:31: error: Argument 2 to "Util" has incompatible type "Impl"; expected "MyProto"  [arg-type]
    util = Util[MyProto](MyProto, Impl())
                                  ^
t.py:27:31: note: Following member(s) of "Impl" have conflicts:
t.py:27:31: note:     attr: expected "str", got "int"
```

Comment: Given my runtime aspect of what I'm trying to do, I'll digress to use ABC's rather than Protocol classes for this case.